# Download .net core generated pdf file with ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core

i am struggling with downloading generated pdf with .net core using ajax call. Basically i have a list of orders which user needs to select and then print pdf output. I can do it using button with action link, but i need to somehow pass in selected values (selected checkboxes), therefore i use ajax and pass in those values.

So far i have this:

html:

```
<button id="btnPrintSelectedOrdersDeliveryLabels">Print labels</button>
```

c#:

```
return File(Convert.FromBase64String(deliveryAPIprintLabelsResult.Labels), "application/pdf", "delivery_labels.pdf");
```

javascript:

```
       $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("PrintDeliveryLabelsByOrderId", "Delivery")',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            orderIds: JSON.stringify(orderIds)
        },
        success: function(result) {

            var blob = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = 'delivery_labels.pdf';

            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);

        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error!');
        }
    });       
}
```

I am pretty sure that error is somewhere in ajax success call, since i get a pdf but it's blank.

Comment: If you look at the downloaded PDF file in the sources tab of the chrome devtools (or similar in other browser), are you sure the file isn't blank? if it is, it's a server side bug.

Comment: @ikkentim response is "JVBERi0xLjcKOCAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZSAvUGFyZW50IDEgMCBSIC....."

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Jquery doesn't support 'blobs' so final solution should be made using XHR.